# ffmpeg multiple files dimensions change

Tags: windows, command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I saw a post on superUser on changing dimensions of a mp4 file which like this 
`FFmpeg -I Input.mp4 -vf scale=460:690 output.mp4` 
but I want to change dimensions of multiple mp4 files in one go so I used the idea which has been used in concat command to generate a list of file names and then using command 
`FFmpeg -i mylist.txt -vf scale=460:690 img%04d.mp4`
 but as in concatenation there's a single output file so for multiple outputs I used wildcard and whole command turned out like 
`FFmpeg -I mylist.txt -vf scale=460:690 img%04d.mp4`
 but still I'm getting a single output file.So any suggestions, please

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to change dimensions of multiple mp4 files in one go

You can use a `for` command to loop and convert the files one at a time. Something like the following.

command line:

```
for /f %i in (mylist.txt) do FFmpeg -I "%i" -vf scale=460:690 "output_%i"
```

batch file:

```
for /f %%i in (mylist.txt) do FFmpeg -I "%%i" -vf scale=460:690 "output_%%i"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: I'm doing everything alright but error is `file: no such file or directory`

Comment: @hackerred Are there spaces in your filenames? See updated answer.

Comment: no they are named numerically like from 1 to 100

Comment: They are like this.I'm using a .bat to generate all file names inside a directory '1.mp4'
'1.mp4'
'10.mp4'
'10.mp4'
'100.mp4'
'100.mp4'
'101.mp4'
'101.mp4'
'102.mp4'
'102.mp4'

Comment: Here's a screenshot [link]http://s32.postimg.org/dlgy71cdx/Screenshot_34.png

Comment: @hackerred Remove the `'`s

Comment: thanks man everything working just that output file names are repeating and I'm being prompted to replace existing file name and file name collisions are occurring in output file names

Comment: @hackerred <shrug> I don't know ffmeg. You need to figure out how to correctly specify the output file name you want.

Comment: @hackerred Use `-i`-, not `-I`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard already doing that but thanks for pointing out